# How to copy a value between parenthesis into another part of the same line

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed, csv

I have a CSV file with many lines like these:

```
1003,CC,L1008,,(LB1) Urbà de Barberà del Vallès,3,,,
1006,CK,L0520,,Móra d'Ebre - Móra la Nova (estació),3,,,
1007,AV,L0358,,Granollers-Terrassa-Manresa,3,,,
1011,DD,L0480,,(781) St. Vicenç Castellet-Castellgalí-Manresa,3,,,
1012,DD,L0481,,(784) Manresa-Castellgalí-St.Vicenç-Monistrol,3,,,
1013,DD,L0487,,(783) Manresa-Pt.Vilomara-St.Vicenç-Monistrol,3,,,
...
```

What I need to do is, if the 5th column starts with `(` copy the value between parenthesis in place of the 3rd column. If not, leave the line as is.

So the result would be:

```
1003,CC,LB1,,(LB1) Urbà de Barberà del Vallès,3,,,
1006,CK,L0520,,Móra d'Ebre - Móra la Nova (estació),3,,,
1007,AV,L0358,,Granollers-Terrassa-Manresa,3,,,
1011,DD,781,,(781) St. Vicenç Castellet-Castellgalí-Manresa,3,,,
1012,DD,784,,(784) Manresa-Castellgalí-St.Vicenç-Monistrol,3,,,
1013,DD,783,,(783) Manresa-Pt.Vilomara-St.Vicenç-Monistrol,3,,,
...
```

I'm thinking on doing it with `sed`, and I know I can capture the part between parenthesis, but I don't know how to replace a text that is not known.

Is it possible to do it with `sed`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Provided that your CSV does not have embedded separators (comma separated fields that contain quoted commas) then this is simple with Awk:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{OFS=FS=","} match($5,/^\([0-9]+\)/) {$3 = substr($5,RSTART+1,RLENGTH-2)} 1' file.csv
1003,CC,L1008,,(LB1) Urbà de Barberà del Vallès,3,,,
1006,CK,L0520,,Móra d'Ebre - Móra la Nova (estació),3,,,
1007,AV,L0358,,Granollers-Terrassa-Manresa,3,,,
1011,DD,781,,(781) St. Vicenç Castellet-Castellgalí-Manresa,3,,,
1012,DD,784,,(784) Manresa-Castellgalí-St.Vicenç-Monistrol,3,,,
1013,DD,783,,(783) Manresa-Pt.Vilomara-St.Vicenç-Monistrol,3,,,
```

Using Sed (with the same restriction):

```
$ sed -E 's/^([^,]*),([^,]*),([^,]*),([^,]*),\(([0-9]+)\)/\1,\2,\5,\4,(\5)/' file.csv
1003,CC,L1008,,(LB1) Urbà de Barberà del Vallès,3,,,
1006,CK,L0520,,Móra d'Ebre - Móra la Nova (estació),3,,,
1007,AV,L0358,,Granollers-Terrassa-Manresa,3,,,
1011,DD,781,,(781) St. Vicenç Castellet-Castellgalí-Manresa,3,,,
1012,DD,784,,(784) Manresa-Castellgalí-St.Vicenç-Monistrol,3,,,
1013,DD,783,,(783) Manresa-Pt.Vilomara-St.Vicenç-Monistrol,3,,,
```

More robustly, using perl's Text::CSV module:

```
$ perl -C -MText::CSV -lne '
    BEGIN{$p = Text::CSV->new()} 
    @f = $p->fields() if $p->parse($_); 
    $f[2] = $1 if $f[4] =~ /^\((\d+)\)/; 
    print join ",", @f
  ' file.csv
1003,CC,L1008,,(LB1) Urbà de Barberà del Vallès,3,,,
1006,CK,L0520,,Móra d'Ebre - Móra la Nova (estació),3,,,
1007,AV,L0358,,Granollers-Terrassa-Manresa,3,,,
1011,DD,781,,(781) St. Vicenç Castellet-Castellgalí-Manresa,3,,,
1012,DD,784,,(784) Manresa-Castellgalí-St.Vicenç-Monistrol,3,,,
1013,DD,783,,(783) Manresa-Pt.Vilomara-St.Vicenç-Monistrol,3,,,
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not in Python? (replace filename with your filename)

```
import re, csv
for line in list(csv.reader(open('filename', 'r'))):
    matches = re.findall('\([0-9]*\)',line[4])
    if matches:
        line[2] = matches[0]
    print(','.join(line))
```

Answer (score 0):

Done by below script

```
count=`awk '{print NR}' filename| sort -nr| sed -n '1p'`

for ((i=1;i<=$count;i++)); do h=`awk -v i="$count" -F ","  'NR==i && $5 ~ /^\(/{print $5}' filename | awk '{print $1}'| sed -e  "s/(//g" -e "s/)//g"| wc -l`; if [[ $h != 0 ]]; then k=`awk -v i="$count" -F ","  'NR==i && $5 ~ /^\(/{print $5}' filename | awk '{print $1}'| sed -e  "s/(//g" -e "s/)//g"`; awk -v i="$count" -v k="$k" -F "," 'NR==i && $5 ~ /^\(/{$3=k;print $0}' filename| sed "s/ /,/g"; else awk -v i="$count" 'NR==i {print $0}' filename; fi; done
```

output

```
1003,CC,LB1,,(LB1),Urbà,de,Barberà,del,Vallès,3,,,
1006,CK,L0520,,Móra d'Ebre - Móra la Nova (estació),3,,,
1007,AV,L0358,,Granollers-Terrassa-Manresa,3,,,
1011,DD,781,,(781),St.,Vicenç,Castellet-Castellgalí-Manresa,3,,,
1012,DD,784,,(784),Manresa-Castellgalí-St.Vicenç-Monistrol,3,,,
1013,DD,783,,(783),Manresa-Pt.Vilomara-St.Vicenç-Monistrol,3,,,
```

Answer (score 0):

The `awk` and `sed` versions that **steeldriver** provided work like a charm, and are very easy to implement in my current environment.

I've improved them a bit to allow also letters, spaces and dots in the code between parenthesis:

```
awk 'BEGIN{OFS=FS=","} match($5,/^\([a-zA-Z0-9 .]+\)/) {$3 = substr($5,RSTART+1,RLENGTH-2)} 1' file.csv

sed -E 's/^([^,]*),([^,]*),([^,]*),([^,]*),\(([a-zA-Z0-9 .]+)\)/\1,\2,\5,\4,(\5)/' file.csv
```

Other versions do also work, but doesn't fit as good in the workflow I'm doing.

Thanks!